# PHP Adding Row with Criteria to Array from str_getcsv

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am pulling data in from reports that generate on my system using 'str_getcsv'. From here I was trying to only add rows where the month is 5/1/2017 to the array $campaignData.

This is how the spreadsheet is set up...

```
Month       Campaign                  Impressions   Clicks
3/1/2017    RCN - Hard Money, s - VA  74            0
4/1/2017    RCN - Branded, s - NY     4322          124
5/1/2017    RCN - Hard Money, s - VA  55            2
5/1/2017    RCN - Branded, s - WI     106           3
6/1/2017    RCN - Hard Money, s - VA  10            0
6/1/2017    RCN - Branded, s - NM     26            4
6/1/2017    RCN - Branded, s - KY     35            2
6/1/2017    RCN - Branded, s - NY     2773          78
1/1/2017    RCN - Branded, s - WI     104           7
```

Here is the method :

```
public function get_awdapi_campaigns($range, $mcc)
{
    global $tableView;
    if ($range == 'Current Month') {
        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../../clients/client_reports/campaigns/' . $mcc . '_THIS_MONTH___campaign.csv'));
    } elseif ($range == 'Last 7 Days') {
        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../../clients/client_reports/campaigns/'
            . $mcc . '_LAST_7_DAYS___campaign.csv'));
    } else {
        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('../../clients/client_reports/campaigns/' . $mcc . '_LAST_MONTH___campaign.csv'));
    };
    array_walk($csv, function (&$a) use ($csv) {
        $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
    });
    array_shift($csv); # remove column header
    foreach ($csv as $key) {
        $month          = $key['Month'];
        $campaign       = $key['Campaign'];
        $impressions    = $key['Impressions'];
        $clicks         = $key['Clicks'];
        $ctr            = $key['CTR'];
        $avgcpc         = number_format($key['Avg. CPC'] / 1000000, 2);
        $avgpos         = $key['Avg. position'];
        $cost           = number_format($key['Cost'] / 1000000, 2);
        $conv           = $key['Conversions'];
        $costperconv    = number_format($key['Cost / conv.'] / 1000000, 2);
        $convrate       = $key['Conv. rate'];
        $sis            = $key['Search Impr. share'];
        $campaignData[] = '<tr><td>' . $month . '</td><td>' . $campaign . '</td><td>' . $impressions . '</td><td>' . $clicks . '</td><td>' . $ctr . '</td><td>' . $avgcpc . '</td><td>' . $avgpos . '</td><td>' . $cost . '</td><td>' . $conv . '</td><td>' . $costperconv . '</td><td>' . $convrate . '</td><td>' . $sis . '</td></tr>';
    }
    $tableView = implode('', $campaignData);
    return $tableView;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? What do you think is wrong with your code?

Comment: This foreach is just mirroring the csv file...is there a way to add rows to the array that meet a certain 'Month' criteria. Basically a foreach row where month = 'May 2017'?

Comment: I have added tags which are matching to question.
I have indented the code throughout.